# MySql - Union across different Servers

Tags: mysql, union

Is there any way to do something like this?

select * from server1.database_name.table
union all
select * from server2.database_name.table

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a table on server1 that uses the FEDERATED storage engine to connect to server2.

Read more [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/federated-storage-engine.html).